# Python/Pandas - Duplicating an index in a new column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with indexes 1,2,3.

```
    Name
1   Rob
2   Mark
3   Alex
```

I want to duplicate that index in a new column so it gets like this:

```
    Name  Number
1   Rob        1
2   Mark       2
3   Alex       3
```

Any ideas?

## EDIT

I forgot one important part: those items in the Numbers column should be turned into string

Comment: df['Number'] = df.index

Comment: This is very trivial to do

Comment: just do `df['Number'] = df.index.astype(str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Number'] = df.index.astype(str)

   Name  Number
1   Rob       1
2  Mark       2
3  Alex       3
```